# Response from background script returns undefined after fetch - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script that send a message to the background script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({site: "stackoverflow", options: { 
    url: url
  }}, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

and my background script has listener:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.site == "stackoverflow") {

      fetch(request.options.url)
      .then( (res) => {
        return res.text()
      })
      .then( (document_text) => {
        sendResponse({"one": "1"})
      })
    }
    //sendResponse({"one": "1"})
});
```

Now, in the fetch, when I try to send the response back, I get `undefined` in the content script. And If I use it outside the fetch:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  //...
      .then( (document_text) => {
        //sendResponse({"one": "1"})
      })
    }
    sendResponse({"one": "1"})
});
```

my content script logs `{"one": "1"}`.

Why am I getting this problem?

Comment: Please check in the developer docs, you need to do `return true` from `onMessage` handler when `sendResponse` is async. I think a similar question has been asked before.

Comment: Oh I think I got it. I returned true in my IF block, and it worked. Thanks!